# Limits at infinity for compound interest

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

I have been revising for my notes and encountered this formula:

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}A\begin{pmatrix}1+\frac r m\end{pmatrix}^{mt} &=\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}A\begin{pmatrix}1+\frac 1 {m/r}\end{pmatrix}^{(m/r)rt}\\
&=A\begin{bmatrix}\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\begin{pmatrix}1+\frac 1 {m/r}\end{pmatrix}^{(m/r)}\end{bmatrix}^{rt}\\
&=Ae^{rt}
\end{align*}
$$

The puzzling part is how do I transit on the first line? In other words, how did this happen?
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}A\begin{pmatrix}1+\frac r m\end{pmatrix}^{mt} &=\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}A\begin{pmatrix}1+\frac 1 {m/r}\end{pmatrix}^{(m/r)rt}\\
\end{align*}
$$
I have been trying to divide by $m/r$ on both sides of the equation but do not know how the power comes in. Any ideas?

**UPDATE: solved**

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}A\begin{pmatrix}1+\frac r m\end{pmatrix}^{mt} &=\overbrace{\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}A\begin{pmatrix}1+\frac 1 {m/r}\end{pmatrix}^{mt}}^{
\text{Divide by }\space r \space \text{on both the numerator & denominator}}\\
&=\overbrace{\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}A\begin{pmatrix}1+\frac 1 {m/r}\end{pmatrix}^{(m/r)rt}}^{
\text{Divide & then multily by }\space r \space \text{on the power}}\\
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Just note that $\frac{r}{m} = \dfrac{1}{\frac{m}{r}}$ (dividing by a fraction is multiplying by its reciprocal), and $m = \frac{m}{r} \cdot r$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two typos. The author(s) did not mean to write $\frac{r}{m/r}$, what was intended is $\frac{1}{m/r}$. And $(m/r)rt$ was intended, not $(m/r)mt$.

**Edit:** Typo has now been corrected. There is no transition in the first line. The fraction
$\frac{1}{m/r}$ is exactly the **same** as $\frac{r}{m}$. Similarly, $(m/r)rt$ is exactly the same thing as $mt$.

The expression is being rewritten as an equivalent expression so that we can use the fact that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x=e$.

Comment: Hello, thank you for helping me spot the typos! I have made the necessary changes. However, I still can't understand the transition part. Could you help?

Comment: I feel very cheated right now...finally got it, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Basically, in the first line, *nothing* was happening, but it was happening in a useful way.

Comment: Yes, I realized! Updated the solution to address that.